# How to alter jQuery validation's remote method response

Tags: php, jquery, validation, remote-validation

I need to validate a phone number through remote method from validation, but also the response i get is not true/false and the form doesn't validate. It is possible to alter the reponse after i use the parameter which is returned?

```
remote: {
                url: "index.php/main/verifyphone",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    phone: function() {
                        return $("#PHONE").val();
                    },
                    product: function() {
                        return $("#choose").chosen().val();
                    }                        
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                    if (response.responseJSON!=false) {
                        $("#GUID").attr('value', response.responseJSON);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }                        
                }                    
            }
```

In this form, the response is treated as a custom message for failure. I need to transform the response to TRUE, after i save the responseJSON, so my form can validate. Any ideas? 
PS: The response from php can be false or an number. If it is a number, validate the form.

Comment: If the response is false, then you can simply return false. If the response is a number, can you return true? So if (response === false) { return false;} else { return true; }

Comment: i have already tried that, but seems that doesn't work. No matter what i return, if isn't equal to true, it takes it as an custom error message.